# How are unittests executed?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I currently have a script that rotates my AWS secret and public access keys. I want to run a unittest against one specific function at the moment.

```
    def get_key(self, data):
        for i in data:
            aws_access_key_id = i.get('AccessKeyId')
        return aws_access_key_id
```

This function loops through data that looks like this:

```
 [{'UserName': 'my.name', 'AccessKeyId': 'my access key', 'Status': 'Active'}]
```

My current test:

```
    def test_get_key(self):
        data_ = old_access_retrieve_data
        expected_output = 'AKIAZJQW7MYGJNHKF22R'
        actual_output = get_key(data_)
        self.assertEqual(expected_output, actual_output)
```

The problem I have is, when I run the tests it appears to run the entire AWS rotation script. This means it is generating an AWS key. I was of the understanding that the function - `get_key` should be run in isolation from the rest of the script due to the way I am calling it.

Am I completely wrong or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you import a file then that file is run. If you have stuff in the script that you don't want to run when the script is imported, that is what `if __name__ == '__main__':` is for.

Answer (score 0):

The Python application that executes your test code, checks the assertions, and gives you test results in your console is called the test runner. This is a command line entry point. It means that if you execute the script alone by running python test.py at the command line, it will call unit test

Comment: So I am calling the test with unittest. I am then expecting it to run just the function I specify. Is this what it should do?